# Custom Site Map Provider for Personal Sites SP 2013

Tags: 2013, my-site, portalsitemapprovider

I made a custom site map provider for the left nav on the My Site Host and it works perfectly, however, all of the personal my sites have a different site map than the host. I thought I could remedy this by creating a custom master page stapler. The funny thing is when I activate the stapler, the css for all the personal sites change, just not the site map on the left nav. Has anyone run into this before? Is there anything I can do about it? I thought maybe it's because SharePoint Server Publishing wasn't on at the site level, but it error's out when I try to Activate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:
https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/sharepoint-2013-customize-followed-sitesdocuments-left-navigation/
The quick links of the personal sites will follow the one of the MySite host.

It worked for me.

Keep me in touch,

Good luck

Comment: Would you like to include some of the contents from the link as part of answer. You can also brief about What was your problem, How you solved it, any code example. This will help improve readability for other visitors as external links have chances to break. :)